# The integral of an elliptic integral: $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\mathbf{K}^2\left ( x \right )}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, elliptic-integrals

> Prove:
> $$\mathcal{I}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\mathbf{K}^2\left ( x \right )}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi ^{4}}{16}\,_7F_6\left ( 
> \dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{5}{4};\dfrac{1}{4},1,1,1,1,1;1 \right )$$

I found this beautiful integral in Yury A.Brychkov's book ***Handbook of Special Functions,Derivatives, Integrals, Series and Other Formulas*** p.278.

---

**My attempt:**

With the representation of elliptic integral by hypergeometric function below
$$\mathbf{K}\left ( x \right )=\frac{\pi }{2}\, _2F_1\left ( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;x^{2} \right )=\frac{\pi }{2}\, _2F_1\left ( \frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4};1;4x^{2}\left ( 1-x^{2} \right ) \right )$$
$$\mathbf{K}^{2}\left ( x \right )=\frac{\pi^{2} }{4}\, _3F_2\left ( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1,1;4x^{2}\left ( 1-x^{2} \right ) \right )$$
hence
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{I}&=\frac{\pi ^{2}}{4} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{\Gamma^{3} \left ( k+\dfrac{1}{2} \right )\left [ 4x^{2}\left ( 1-x^{2} \right ) \right ]^{k}}{\Gamma^{3} \left ( \dfrac{1}{2} \right )\Gamma^{3} \left ( k+1 \right )}\mathrm{d}x\,\,\left ( x^{2}\rightarrow x \right )\\
&=\frac{\pi ^{2}}{8} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{\Gamma^{3} \left ( k+\dfrac{1}{2} \right )\left [ 4x\left ( 1-x \right ) \right ]^{k}}{\Gamma^{3} \left ( \dfrac{1}{2} \right )\Gamma^{3} \left ( k+1 \right )}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{\pi ^{2}}{8}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{\Gamma^{4} \left ( k+\dfrac{1}{2} \right )4^{k}}{\Gamma^{3} \left ( \dfrac{1}{2} \right )\Gamma^{2} \left ( k+1 \right )\Gamma \left ( 2k+\dfrac{3}{2} \right )}\\
&=\frac{\pi ^{2}}{8}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{\Gamma^{4} \left ( k+\dfrac{1}{2} \right )4^{k}}{\Gamma^{2} \left ( \dfrac{1}{2} \right )\Gamma^{2} \left ( k+1 \right )\Gamma \left ( k+\dfrac{3}{4} \right )\Gamma \left ( k+\dfrac{5}{4} \right )2^{2k+\frac{1}{2}}}\\
&=\frac{\pi ^{2}}{8\sqrt{2}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{\Gamma^{4} \left ( k+\dfrac{1}{2} \right )}{\Gamma^{2} \left ( \dfrac{1}{2} \right )\Gamma^{2} \left ( k+1 \right )\Gamma \left ( k+\dfrac{3}{4} \right )\Gamma \left ( k+\dfrac{5}{4} \right )}\\
&=\frac{\pi ^{2}\Gamma ^{2}\left ( \dfrac{1}{2} \right )}{8\sqrt{2}\Gamma \left ( \dfrac{3}{4} \right )\Gamma \left ( \dfrac{5}{4} \right )}\, _4F_3\left ( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1,\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};1 \right )\\
&=\frac{\pi ^{2}}{4}\, _4F_3\left ( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1,\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};1 \right )
\end{align*}

But the numerical result doesn't match.Is there something wrong with my solution?

Any help will be appreciated!

---

Another solution (by Editor):
The originial integral equals to $\int_0^1 K'(x)^2dx$. Now use that

> $$\frac{4}{\pi^2}K'(x)_=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (4n+1) \left(\frac{\binom{2n}n}{4^n}\right)^3 P_{2n}(x)$$

and Parseval theorem of FL expansion. The result immediately follows.

Comment: Your first identity $$\frac{\pi }{2}\, _2F_1\left ( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;x^{2} \right )=\frac{\pi }{2}\, _2F_1\left ( \frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4};1;4x^{2}\left ( 1-x^{2} \right ) \right )$$ holds only for $x<2^{-1/2}$. See the conditions for [quadratic transform](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E18) used.

Comment: @PaulEnta I see.Thank you! By the way, do you have any idea how to prove the integral.

Comment: @PaulEnta sry. It was my fault.

Comment: A proof can be found in [Moments of products of elliptic integrals](http://people.sutd.edu.sg/~james_wan/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/mkint.pdf) by J.G. Wan. The integral is transformed into a triple integral which is of the required form to apply a theorem by Zudilin which gives a triple integral representation of the very-well poised $\,_7F_6$ hypergeometric series. Many similar integrals of products of elliptic integrals are also given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This result and a sketch for its proof can be found in [Moments of products of elliptic integrals](http://people.sutd.edu.sg/~james_wan/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/mkint.pdf) by J.G. Wan. It uses a theorem by Zudilin which gives a triple integral representation for some very-well poised $\,_7F_6$ hypergeometric series :
\begin{align}
 &\iiint_{\left[ 0,1\right]^3}\frac{x^{h_2-1}y^{h_3-1}z^{h_4-1}(1-x)^{h_0-h_2-h_3
 }(1-y)^{h_0-h_3-h_4}(1-z)^{h_0-h_4-h_5}}{\left( 1-x\left( 1-y\left( 1-z \right)  \right)\right)^{h_1}}\,dxdydz\\
 &=\frac{\Gamma(h_0+1)\prod_{j=2}^4\Gamma(h_j)\prod_{j=1}^4\Gamma(h_0+1-h_j-h_{j+1})}{\prod_{j=1}^5\Gamma(h_0+1-h_j)}\times\\
 &\times\,_7F_6\left( \left. \begin{matrix}h_0,1+h_0/2,h_1,h_2,h_3,h_4,h_5\\h_0/2,1+h_0-h_1,1+h_0-h_2,1+h_0-h_3,1+h_0-h_4,1+h_0-h_5\end{matrix}\right|1 \right)
\end{align}
To evaluate 
\begin{align}
 \mathcal{I}&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\mathbf{K}^2\left ( x \right )}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\\
 &=\int_{0}^{1}\mathbf{K'}^2\left ( y \right )\mathrm{d}y
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{K'}\left ( x \right )=\mathbf{K}\left ( \sqrt{1-x^2} \right )$ (note that the arguments of the elliptic integrals are the elliptical parameter - not the elliptic modulus), we use the two integral representations
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{K}\left ( s\right )&=\int_0^1\frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-s^2t^2)}}\\
 &=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)(1-s^2x)}} \tag{A}
\end{align} 
and also, from the latter,
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{K'}\left ( a\right )&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{du}{\sqrt{u(1-u)(1-(1-a^2)u)}}\\
 &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{a^2}^1\frac{dv}{\sqrt{v(1-v)(v-a^2)}}\tag{B}
\end{align}
obtained using the change of variable $v=1-(1-a^2)u$. Then,
\begin{align}
 \mathcal{I}&\overset{\text{(B)}}{=}\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1da\mathbf{K}(\sqrt{1-a^2})\int_{a^2}^1\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y(1-y)(y-a^2)}}\\
 &=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1dy \int_0^{\sqrt{y}}\frac{\mathbf{K}(\sqrt{1-a^2})}{\sqrt{y(1-y)(y-a^2)}}\,da\\
 &=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1dy \int_0^1\frac{\mathbf{K}(\sqrt{1-yz})}{\sqrt{y(1-y)(1-z)}}\,dz\\
 &\overset{\text{(A)}}{=}\frac{1}{8}\int_0^1dy \int_0^1\frac{dz}{\sqrt{y(1-y)(1-z)}}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)(1-x(1-yz))}}\\
 &\overset{z\to 1-z}{=}\frac{1}{8}\iiint_{\left[ 0,1\right]^3}\frac{(xyz)^{-1/2}\left[ (1-x)(1-y)(1-z)\right]^{-1/2}}{\sqrt{1-x\left( 1-y\left( 1-z \right) \right)}}dxdydz
\end{align}
With $h_j=\frac{1}{2}$ for $j=0,1,2,3,4,5$, using the integral representation for the hypergeometric series  given above
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}&= \frac{1}{8}\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\left[\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}  \right) \right]^7
\,_7F_6\left( \left. \begin{matrix}1/2,1/2,1/2,1/2,1/2,1/2,5/4\\1/4,1,1,1,1,1\end{matrix}\right|1 \right)
\end{align}
which is the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but some (hopefully interesting) considerations, too long to fit in a comment.

I prefer to denote the complete elliptic integral of the first kind by regarding its argument as the elliptic *modulus* rather than the elliptic parameter. According to this convention (which is also Mathematica's one) the integral of interest is
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x K^2(x^2)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx =\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{K^2(x)}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,dx$$
where twice the RHS can be regarded as the $L^2$ squared norm of $\frac{K(x)}{\sqrt[4]{1-x}}$ over $(0,1)$.
The [Fourier-Legendre series expansion of $K(x)$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.03221) is fairly simple and the Fourier-Legendre series expansion of $\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{1-x}}$ can be computed from Rodrigues formula. To recover the mentioned result, it should be enough to compute a convolution, then apply Parseval's identity. Or write the original integral as
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-x^2\cos^2\theta)(1-x^2\cos^2\phi)}}\,d\theta\,d\phi\,dx $$
or
$$ \iiint_{(0,\pi/2)^3}\frac{\sin\eta}{\sqrt{(1-\sin^2\eta\cos^2\theta)(1-\sin^2\eta^2\cos^2\phi)}}\,d\theta\,d\phi\,d\eta $$
then apply Fubini's theorem / [Beuker-Calabi-Kolk-type](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.3602) / reverse hyperspherical coordinates substitutions.